# jquery - Select all elements after a certain element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list similar to below and would like to only select all of the elements after the `#everything_after` element.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div id="everything_after"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use nextAll to get the following divs.

Try:

```
$("#everything_after").nextAll();
```

Comment: What if I want to select the next elements outside of the parent container? nextAll() only selects the items on same parent.

Answer (score 18):

See: CSS3 General Siblings Selector

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector

```
$("#everything_after ~ div")...
```

Comment: this is a much more general answer

Answer (score 1):

**CASE-1:** when the `id=""` or the `class=""` selector is known:

```
$("#everything_after").nextAll();
//selects any of the next sibling elements, like <div>, <p>, <i>... etc tags.

//--or--
$("#everything_after").nextAll("div");
//selects only the next sibling <div> tags;
```

**CASE-2:** when the index of the item is known:

```
$("#container > div:nth-child(6)").nextAll();
//--or--
$("#container > div:eq(5)").nextAll();
```

Answer (score -6):

selects all the elements

```
$('#element *').attr('selected','selected');
```